# pl/sql can't modify constraint defferable

Tags: oracle, plsql, constraints

I want to make constraint deferrable so I've wrote this code:

```
alter table life_cycle_phases modify constraint SOME_T_NAME_UNIQUE INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE;
```

but orace returns mistake:

```
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

what am i doing wrong?

UPDATE:
ok, i see, once i've created not deferrable constraint, i can't check it's state, but i need to!
my problem is: i need to disable all constraints, add row in table,which was random chosen(in fact i don't know in which table the row will be inserted) then enable all constraints.`enable novalidate` doesn't work, it validates rows, deferrable also doesn't work, what should  do?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to disable a constraint, insert data which violates the constraint, and then re-enable the constraint in such a manner that the invalid row isn't detected, correct?

Comment: @BobJarvis, yes you're right!

Comment: Then why have the constraint in the first place?

Comment: @BobJarvis,  it's my task in university)

Comment: Tell your instructor that somebody on StackOverflow said it can't be done. And perhaps that's the point of the assignment - to find out that it can't be done. A referential integrity constraint such as this is a promise that either A) something that shouldn't happen won't happen, or B) something that must happen will happen. In this case you've got a UNIQUE contraint, saying that the values in a particular field or group of fields must be unique. If that turns out not to be true Bad Things can happen - such as the database returning very wrong results for a query. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

In general, `MODIFY` constraint is to just change the state of it. For instance, enable it, disable it..

From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53338).. You cannot change the state of a `NOT DEFERRABLE` constraint to `INITIALLY DEFERRED`.

> Restrictions on Modifying Constraints   Modifying constraints is
>   subject to the following restrictions:
>
> •You cannot change the state of a NOT DEFERRABLE constraint to
>   INITIALLY DEFERRED.
>
> •If you specify this clause for an index-organized table, then you
>   cannot specify any other clauses in the same statement.
>
> •You cannot change the NOT NULL constraint on a foreign key column of
>   a reference-partitioned table, and you cannot change the state of a
>   partitioning referential constraint of a reference-partitioned table.

So, drop the constraint first and recreate it.
You may use the below to generate the DDL of the constraint.

```
--For referential integrity constraints.
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('REF_CONSTRAINT',CONSTRAINT_NAME,OWNER)
--For other kinds of constraints.
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('CONSTRAINT',CONSTRAINT_NAME,OWNER)
```

Or try this.. ( Courtesy : https://gist.github.com/sdeming/869717 ...I haven't tested!!)

```
select 'alter table ' || source_table || ' add constraint ' || constraint_name || ' foreign key (' || con_columns || ') references ' || target_table || ' (' || ind_columns || ') enable' data 
  from (select constraint_name, source_table, target_index, target_table, con_columns, wm_concat(column_name) ind_columns
          from (select a.constraint_name, a.source_table, a.target_index, b.table_name target_table, a.con_columns, b.column_name, b.column_position
                  from (select a.constraint_name, a.source_table, a.target_index, wm_concat(a.column_name) con_columns
                          from (select a.constraint_name, 
                                       a.table_name source_table, 
                                       a.r_constraint_name target_index, 
                                       b.column_name,
                                       b.position
                                  from user_constraints a
                                 inner join user_cons_columns b on (b.constraint_name = a.constraint_name)
                                 where a.constraint_type = 'R'
                                   and a.constraint_name = 'LIFE_CYCLE_PHASES_NAME_UNIQUE'
                                 order by a.constraint_name, b.position) a
                        group by constraint_name, source_table, target_index) a
                  inner join user_ind_columns b on (b.index_name = a.target_index)
                  order by constraint_name, b.column_position) 
          group by constraint_name, source_table, target_index, target_table, con_columns);
```

And then DROP it,

```
alter table OWNER.life_cycle_phases drop constraint LIFE_CYCLE_PHASES_NAME_UNIQUE ;
```

Finally recreate the constraint only using the generated DDL.

Comment: but how can I create it again, when I don't know on which column it was created? (see update)